# How do you add parameters in Root segment in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I tried something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{ scrollTo: '#contact' }">Contact</a>


this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    if (params['scrollTo']) {
        //some code here
    }
});
```

Doesn't seem to cycle trough parameters

Comment: For query params you use `route.queryParams`